# How to see old history in zsh

Tags: zsh

I am using zsh with Prezto, my question is why I only see a limit number of my history:

```
~ >>> history2651  git checkout -- modules/prompt/functions/prompt_sorin_setup
 2652  git diff runcoms/zshrc
 2653  git diff
 2654  cd ~
 2655  cd Work/TEST
 2656  git status
 2657  rm test.m
 2658  git checkout -- apps/TravelApp/TravelApp/Views/Form/AXFormDateCell.xib
 2659  zsh --version
 2660  om ~/.zshrc&
 2663  ls -la
```

Here is my zshrc setting, I have history size set to a large number

```
# Increase history file size
export HISTSIZE=1000000000
export SAVEHIST=$HISTSIZE
setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY

# from http://zanshin.net/2013/02/02/zsh-configuration-from-the-ground-up/
# ===== Basics
setopt no_beep # don't beep on error
setopt interactive_comments # Allow comments even in interactive shells (especially for Muness)

# ===== Changing Directories
setopt auto_cd # If you type foo, and it isn't a command, and it is a directory in your cdpath, go there
setopt cdablevarS # if argument to cd is the name of a parameter whose value is a valid directory, it will become the current directory
setopt pushd_ignore_dups # don't push multiple copies of the same directory onto the directory stack

# ===== Expansion and Globbing
setopt extended_glob # treat #, ~, and ^ as part of patterns for filename generation

# ===== History
setopt append_history # Allow multiple terminal sessions to all append to one zsh command history
setopt extended_history # save timestamp of command and duration
setopt inc_append_history # Add comamnds as they are typed, don't wait until shell exit
setopt hist_expire_dups_first # when trimming history, lose oldest duplicates first
setopt hist_ignore_dups # Do not write events to history that are duplicates of previous events
setopt hist_ignore_space # remove command line from history list when first character on the line is a space
setopt hist_find_no_dups # When searching history don't display results already cycled through twice
setopt hist_reduce_blanks # Remove extra blanks from each command line being added to history
setopt hist_verify # don't execute, just expand history
setopt share_history # imports new commands and appends typed commands to history

# ===== Completion
setopt always_to_end # When completing from the middle of a word, move the cursor to the end of the word
setopt auto_menu # show completion menu on successive tab press. needs unsetop menu_complete to work
setopt auto_name_dirs # any parameter that is set to the absolute name of a directory immediately becomes a name for that directory
setopt complete_in_word # Allow completion from within a word/phrase

unsetopt menu_complete # do not autoselect the first completion entry
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
history
```

is equivalent to

```
fc -l
```

which is in turn equivalent to

```
fc -l -16 -1
```

See

```
man zshbuiltins
```

So if you want to see a larger range, supply it to the command.  For example:

```
history -1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you wanted I always recommend to alias this history search function so looks through it easier.

```
alias s='search'
search() {
   history -i | grep "$1"
}
```

Which outputs results similar to:

```
 2992  2020-11-13 15:56  terraform init
 3000  2020-11-13 16:03  cd .terraform.d
 3016  2020-11-13 16:24  mkdir terraform-modules
```

Answer (score 0):

## All zsh history

```bash
history 0
```

you can use like alias

```bash
alias history='history 0'
```